# Laravel migration fails with SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-migrations

I'm trying to add a migration with laravel. This is mi migration file.

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('sl_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('title')->nullable();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('sl_images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('image')->nullable();
        $table->integer('sl_category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->integer('display_order')->nullable();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('sl_images', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign('sl_category_id')->references('id')->on('sl_categories')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}

public function down() {
    Schema::dropIfExists('sl_images');
    Schema::dropIfExists('sl_categories');
}
```

But unfortunately I'm getting this error.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `sl_images`
>   add constraint `sl_images_sl_category_id_foreign` foreign key
>   (`sl_category_id`) references `sl_categories` (`id`) on delete
>   cascade)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. The issue is **InnoDB does not permit the creation of a foreign key constraint where a column references a nonmatching column type**. If simply said, 
This is a big integer

```
$table->bigIncrements('id');
```

and this is a simple integer.,

```
 $table->integer('sl_category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

So we have to change the later line to **bigInteger**,

```
$table->bigInteger('sl_category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
```

I'm adding this answer in case someone else will find some use of it.